# LDAP callback functionality

Tags: aem

Masters,

I'm trying to implement LDAP callback functionality by  referring to [this](http://wem.help.adobe.com/enterprise/en_US/10-0/core/administering/ldap_authentication.html) article under "CALLBACKS"

I've configured LDAP without issue. My requirement is assign ldap user to CRX group depending on attribute in DS server. Now As per my understanding, when LDAP user will attempt login first time then CQ will automatically call my class which implements Callback interface. Please correct me if I am wrong.

So, I decided to create bundle which implements Callback interface. With my little knowledge I have done this so far -

i) In CRXDE lite, I added one bundle under geometrixx project and attached is the simple code but during building bundle I got error saying that Callback cannot be resolved to a type.

```
import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.User;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Group;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials;

public class SyncUser implements com.day.crx.security.ldap.sync.Callback{

@Override
 public void onUserSync(User userToBeSynched, Map<String, Value[]> attributes,
 ValueFactory valueFactory) throws RepositoryException {
 Iterator iter = attributes.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
    javax.jcr.Value val =  (javax.jcr.Value)mEntry.getValue();
              // Error** [Ljavax.jcr.Value; cannot be cast to javax.jcr.Value
    System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + val.getString());
 }
 }

@Override
public void onGroupSync(Group group,
                        Map<String, Value[]> attributes,
                        ValueFactory vf) throws RepositoryException{
    System.out.println("Hello onGroupSync");//do my stuff

 }
```

}

I could not find any documentation about this com.day.crx.security.ldap.sync.Callback interface. Kindly guide me. Appreciate your help

Comment: You're just going to have to find that documentation.

Comment: @EJP, I was able to resolve the maven dependency issue but now I'm getting error while type casting Value object. I do not understand why "L" is appended as Ljavax.jcr.Value which is coming in map.

Answer (score 0):

Here is at least *some* documentation for com.day.crx.security.ldap.sync.Callback: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/core/administering/ldap_authentication.html#Callbacks

The [doc you referenced](http://wem.help.adobe.com/enterprise/en_US/10-0/core/administering/ldap_authentication.html#Callbacks) says this:

> The callback interface is located in the crx-auth-ldap module and has
>   the following methods that need to be implemented:
>
> You need at least the following dependencies (jar files) to create and
>   build a callback class:
>
> ```
> jcr-<version>.jar
> crx-auth-<version>.jar
> ```
>
> Both are bundled with the CRX Explorer Web Application and can be
>   extracted from the war file.
>
> After you compiled and packaged the callback class you need to make it
>   available to CRX. The easiest way is to place the the custom callback
>   implementation along with the CRX webapp at
>   crx-quickstart/server/runtime/0/_crx/WEB-INF/[lib|classes].